"Simulate this circuit" disappeared
Yesterday, in SE EE, I noticed that "Simulate this circuit" below schematics disappeared. See for example, this answer.
What can be the problem? Maybe it is somehow related to the new image hosting?

IMO, this belongs here on MSE. While the specific thing does only affect a single site, it's nearly certain that it's the result of the network-wide change in the image uploader, given that the "simulate this circuit" functionality is directly tied into the URL used for those images. All of the bugs for this network-wide project are supposed to be here on MSE.

It's been posted about on electronics meta a few hours ago, but may be symptomatic of network-wide issues to come.

@W.O. no, since this is unique to a single site. It is off topic here.

That'd been my initial reaction, but rethought it and withdrew the close vote on reflection. When I search for related posts here, there aren't any (yet). So maybe it's a one-shot for that meta. Frankly I'm undecided. @ShadowWizardLoveZelda

@W.O. if other unique features are bugged, each deserves its own bug report on the dedicated per-site meta. I had no idea what "Simulate this circuit" is at all, and would have voted to close this as "unclear", or "not related to Stack Exchange" if not for the comments which led me to realize there's such a feature in one of the SE sites.

Fair enough. I take it there's a channel through which the staff get to know about per-site meta bug reports (at least if there's loads). @ShadowWizardLoveZelda

Off-topic or on-topic, this does not contain sufficient context. For example, where did the "Simulate this circuit" below schematics disappear? Please add the information (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** without *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now). Thanks in advance.

@W.O. yes they (should?) monitor all meta sites.

@Aaron since this is pretty high priority (missing important feature) can you perhaps poke a developer to take a look? You know I don't ask such things on ordinary bugs. Thanks for sending it to review anyway. :)

@AaronBertrand ah, so that makes it actually [tag:status-planned]. Cheers!

@tanj any elaboration? what was the cause? what was the fix?

Short and simple answer - we just missed a spot in the code. We've re-processed a handful of EE posts that had circuits uploaded that were missing the "simulate this circuit" link.
